# Make Gravity Forms Hidden Field Required?

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I have a Wordpress site that uses Gravity Forms, including hidden fields which are required for proper functionality.  Is there a way to make hidden fields on forms built with gravity forms required?

I will be sending out an email with a URL linking to this form which auto-populates these hidden fields.  However, I'd like to make these hidden fields required, or prevent the form being submitted if these hidden fields are not set, which may happen if a user navigates to the form manually instead of navigating to it via a generated URL.

I wish to avoid the perception that the form has been submitted when it has only been submitted with partial information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, code-free solution would be to use conditional logic to only show the submit button if your hidden fields are not empty. Here's what the settings might look like:

[image]

You can take this a step further and use the opposite conditional logic to show an HTML field with a custom message letting the user know *why* they can't submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

a hidden form element can't be required.

> elements of type hidden let web developers include data that cannot be seen or modified by users when a form is submitted.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

If you put a hidden value, make sure you put it with a value to be sent or make sure that before submit, via javascript you edit that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use two CSS classes to hide your field:
"gf_hidden" or "gf_invisible"

It won't show the Validation Message if it isn't filled though, so the user may not know what is missing from the submission:

The folk at Gravity Perks have a nice page explaining it in more detail though.
https://gravitywiz.com/how-to-hide-gravity-forms-product-fields/